# Ignore the emit of a parent component when clicking on the slot child component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to ignore the the emit from the click on the DataTable row if I've also clicked on the Button inside the slot. I've seen this done with native components with `@click.prevent`. Not sure how to get it working with Vue components and emits.

```
<template>
<DataTable @click="handleRowClick">
  <template v-slot:action="{ row }">
    <Button @click="handleButtonClick">
      Button
    </Button>
  </template>
</DataTable>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {
    DataTable,
    Button
  },
  methods: {
    handleRowClick(){
      console.log("Only the table row has been clicked, redirect");
    },
    handleButtonClick(){
      console.log("Button inside table component slot has been clicked, do something but don't redirect");
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [@click.stop](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Modificadores-de-eventos):

```
<Button @click.stop="handleButtonClick">
  Button
</Button>
```

If you have a custom componet without click emit. You need to add .native too:

```
<Button @click.native.stop="handleButtonClick">
  Button
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your first click add the modifier `self`

```
<DataTable @click.self="handleRowClick">
```